# Handle multiple events in gpio

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, gpio

I'm new to embedded programming and I apologise in advance for any confusion.

I need to handle multiple events from different devices connected to a gpio. These events need to be monitored continually. This means that after one event is generated and handled, the code needs to keep monitoring the device for other events.

I understand the concept of interruptions and polling in Linux (the kernel gets an interruption and dispatch it to the handler which goes on up to the callee of an epoll which is inside an infinite loop while(1)-like).

This is fine for one-time, single-event toy models. In a embedded system with limited resources such as the [AT91SAM9x5](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/AT91SAM9x5#AT91SAM9x5-LinuxKernel) that runs at 400mhz and has 128mb of ram what can I do ? I believe that the while(1)-like pattern isn't the best choice. I've heard good things about thread pool solution but at the heart of each thread don't we find a while(1) ?

What are my options to attack this problem ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `I believe that the while(1)-like pattern isn't the best choice.` why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an embedded system, the AT91SAM is actually quite "resource rich" rather than resource limited. The idea is the same as if you writing it using Linux: you set up a pin interrupt, and in your interrupt handler, you do some minimal processing and maybe set up some global data so that your main loop "while (1)" can detect the situation and then process the information in the non-interrupt context. Basically you want the interrupt handler to finish as quickly as possible so that it can handle the next interrupt.

In most systems, interrupts can be pended or nested. With systems that allow nested interrupts, you have to make sure that it does not trash the context of the previous interrupt that is still being executed.

The actual communication scheme between the interrupt handler and the main code depends on your requirement. You can even use an RTOS with support for such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what is your application and what are your constrains but here are some of the common methods to monitor gpio pins for event

- In many of the newer controllers, all GPIO pins are capable of generating a combined interrupt. You can use this to trigger an ISR call on any change on any of the pins and then inside the ISR detect which specific pin triggered it.
- If there is nothing else your controller should be doing, then there is nothing wrong is a while(1) loop continuously monitoring all port pins and triggering relevant actions
- If none of the above solutions are acceptable, you can perhaps try to load a small OS like FreeRTOS on your controller and then use different tasks to monitor port pins
- A lighter version of the above method is to have a configure a timer interrupt and poll for all the port pins inside it. You can then save the state of pins in global variable and use that in the main loop to take relevant actions.